$|ta+(1-t)b|^p\leq t|a|^p + (1-t)|b|^p - \frac{t(1-t)}{C}|a-b|^p$ for a Hilbert space and $p\geq 2$
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. For any $p\geq 2, t\in (0,1)$ and $a,b\in H$, I would like to prove (or disprove) that there exists a constant $C=C(p,t)$ that can depend on $p,t$ such that
$\begin{equation} \|ta+(1-t)b\|^p \leq t\|a\|^p +(1-t)\|b\|^p -\frac{t(1-t)}{C}\|a-b\|^p \end{equation}\tag*{}$
My attempt.
I believe the $p=2$ case is exactly the same as proving that $\|x\|^2$ is strongly convex, as seen in this question: Prove that function $w \mapsto m \|w\|^2$ is strongly convex.  However, I am not sure how to generalize this argument to $p>2$, and I was not able to come up with a simple counterexample.

Our inequality says that $\|x\|^p$ is uniformly convex with modulus $\phi(t)=\frac{1}{C}t^p$. This is proven in Example 10.14 in Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces by Heinz H. Bauschke and Patrick L. Combettes. Their proof is basically that since $\|x\|^2$ is uniformly convex (by parallelogram law), so is $\|x\|^p = (\|x\|^2)^{p/2}$. By their Proposition 10.13, $f\geq 0$ uniformly convex implies $f^p$ uniformly convex. Note that the claim that $\frac{1}{C}t^p$ is a modulus follows from Proposition 10.13.
